# How ensure <div> elements gets completely loaded in AJAX call before we set focus to a particular control

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms

I am having aspx page. In this page i have [div id="popUp"]. This gets loaded only when user clicks a button.

I am using jquery ajax call to Load data and place the returned HTML into the matched element. I am doing all this in common js file.

Something like:
1. $( "#popUp" ).load( "xyz/test.html");
2. $('FirstControl').focus();

So after the execution of first statement the DIV in my aspx page has the data from test.html but i don't have focus on first control of the test.html page.

i think this is because of asynchronous call.

Can anyone suggest me how can i set focus on specific element of this loading page xyz/test.html.

P.S.- I don't want to set it into document.ready of this html or page_load() since it has few short comings.

If its due to asynchronous and delay in loading OR focussing before element is loaded, can you please suggest anything that would allow these 2 statements to occur sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the load method:

```
$( "#popUp" ).load( "xyz/test.html", function() {
    $('FirstControl').focus();
});
```

That callback will be executed once the ajax has finished loading the content into that div.